# Minecraft command blocks, how do I detect a block on the ground, for example stone

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I just can’t find anyway to do it I’ve already tired so many commands but they are all just old or outdated. If anyone could help me that would be great

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Perhaps you can tell us a bit more about what you've tried and we can troubleshoot your commands from there?

Comment: 'on the ground' what do you mean by this? do you mean on the surface? under a player's feet? under the command block?

Comment: @AMJ "on the ground" is simply "not falling", I find that pretty clear. And I'm pretty sure there's an NBT tag for that.

Comment: @FabianRöling But stone blocks never fall. It was specifically stated that he was testing for a "block on the ground", not an item.

Comment: @AMJ Oh, right, I had read "item" into this, but it isn't actually mentioned anywhere. Also, apparently this is MCBE, so NBT is not a solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you tell if a specific item is dropped? What about its name?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/376566/can-you-tell-if-a-specific-item-is-dropped-what-about-its-name)

Answer (score -1):

I finally got it, but thank you all for trying to help, and I’m sorry I didn’t put the command that I used.
The command I used was `/testfor @e[type=item,name=paper]`.