# Can you tell if a specific item is dropped? What about its name?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

In Java Edition, I can test for a dropped item on the floor by using NBT:

```
/execute if entity @e[type=item,nbt={Item:{id:"minecraft:green_wool"}}]
```

But in Bedrock Edition, NBT is inaccessible from commands. Is there still a way to test for a dropped item on the ground?

What about testing for a *named* item drop?

This would allow you to run certain commands when a specific item is dropped, for example, if the player drops a compass they could be teleported to the spawn of your world, or have a message shown to them.

See also: [Detecting items in the player's inventory](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/371922/188492)

---

[Browse more workarounds for getting/setting NBT in Bedrock Edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/334102/250180)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Commands

```
/testfor @e[type=item,name="Ghast Tear"]
```

This command will activate when a ghast tear is dropped.

```
/kill @e[type=item,name="Lime Wool"]
```

This command runs when a Lime Wool is dropped.

```
/testfor @e[type=item,name="Spooky Pumpkin"]
```

If you name an item “Spooky Pumpkin” and drop it, this runs.

## Notes

- This is still compatible with the color formatting codes (`§`), so don’t worry!
- If your item name does not contain spaces and consists only of the characters in the following line, you may type the name directly, without having to include the quotation marks:

  ```
  +-.0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
  ```

  If your name contains a character *not* in this list, you will need to surround your name with quotation marks `"`, like in the above examples. To include a quotation mark as *part* of the name, escape them with a `\`:

  ```
  /testfor @e[type=item,name="some name with spaces and \"quotation marks\""]
  ```

## Limitations

- If you name an item “Ghast Tear”, the ghast tear command will run even if it were something else, like dirt.
- This method requires the name of the item in the host's texture pack to always be the name matching the command block, meaning it won't work if the user has a special texture pack on that changes the name or their language is set to something else. You can solve this problem by:

  - Rename the item if possible
  - Change every language file the game has to make the name of the item the same across all languages, which will require you to include a resource pack in the world/world download
  - Have multiple checks for each possible language name
- The entity count returned by a `/testfor` of this may not reflect the number of dropped items, because when two items with the same properties are dropped next to each other, they like to group up into a single entity representing a stack of one or more items.